# Let statement in Explorer?

Tags: javascript, let

My project (with HTML and JavaScript) doesn't work in Internet Explorer and I think that is because I use a `let` statement in a JS method. Can I add some external libraries that makes it possible to read the `let` statements? Or can I rewrite the function? I don't really know how the let method works so can anyone tell me how to rewrite these lines:

```
initializeData = function()
{
  //Check URL and QueryString
  var url = window.location.href.toString();
  var queryString = (url.split("?"))[1];

  if (queryString == undefined || queryString=="" || queryString==null)
    resetData();
  else //filter data based on URL QueryString
  {
   const query = decodeURI(queryString);
   const result = query.split('&');
   result.forEach(function(item){
       const [cat, values] = item.split('='); //ERROR
       const isArray = cat.endsWith('[]');
       let pair;
     if (isArray)
     {
         const p =  values;
         pair = { cat, 'values': [values] };
     }
     else
     {
         pair = {cat, values };
     }
   currentFilters.push(pair);
   });
  RunFilter();
 }
}
```

I need `pair` to be on the same structure since I am using it in the `RunFilter()` method.

Comment: Try running your code through babel: http://babeljs.io/repl ie also doesn't support array destructuring.

Comment: https://www.caniuse.com/#search=let

Comment: For information on what "let" is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: It'll be a while yet before we can safely use ES6 without [transpiling](https://css-tricks.com/transpiling-es6/).

Comment: Okay thank you. I tried to comment out all of the lines and then add them back one by one. If "const [cat, values] = item.split('=');" is included I'm not able to use Explorer. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Destructuring assignment `[foo,bar] = [1,2]` is another ES6 construct that IE [doesn't support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring).    ES6 browser support is not yet universal, you need to transpile it down to ES5.

Comment: `let split = item.split('='); //ERROR
const cat = split[0];
const values = split[1];`

Comment: You can surely use `var pair={cat:cat,values:values};if(isArray){ /*overwrite the pair */pair={cat:cat,values:[values]}}`. Though IE has added support for let in IE11, i'm not sure up to what extent we can trust it to behave normally.

Comment: just use `var` in place of `const` and `let` - it's the es6 way of declaring variables so you know if they are constants or not